# Ionic: Change ion-navicon color

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a navigation bar:

```
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-green-mint" align-title="center">
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>

        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon menu-icon" menu-toggle="left">
            </button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
```

I want to change the color of my navigation icon. For 'normal' icons like:

```
<i class="icon menu-icon ion-home"></i>
```

I just needed to add the css:

```
.menu-icon {
    color: white;
}
```

but this does not work for the navigation icon.

So how can i set its color to be white?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a working example from [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVWpEO) on how the change in CSS actually works. The code copy/paste here (I used orange instead of white, just to prove point).

```js
angular.module('mySuperApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {

});
```

```css
.menu-icon{
  color:orange;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="mySuperApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
      Toggle button
    </title>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    
    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    
  </head>
  <body class="padding" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    
    <div class="botones">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <button class="button button-block button-positive"><i class="icon menu-icon ion-home"></i>
          Click me
        </button>
      </div>
      
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, since you don't see this change, you have to show the code for as where are you making the CSS change. Are you perhaps using SASS? If so, you would have to change the sass files then.

The best way to check if you changed the CSS correctly is to inspect the button (Firebug, Chrome dev tools) and see if the correct CSS is applied.

Comment: i added the `menu-icon` to the `button` inside the `ion-nav-buttons`. It does not make the nav-icon white. So the solution dos not work :(

Comment: Yes, but where did you put the CSS rule? Full proof, though a bit dirty solution, would be to add the inline style to your icon like this: `<i class="icon ion-home" style="color:orange !important;"></i>`

Comment: with inline script it works! but not with `<button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon menu-icon" menu-toggle="left">`

Comment: It's not enough to add `menu-icon` class to the class list of the button. You still have to put this CSS rule in your CSS file. However, for such a quick fix, I'm guessing this should suffice. Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it helped you. Good luck with you project!

Comment: yes i will. but i would like to understand what you mean by "put this CSS rule in your CSS file"? i have `.menu-icon {
    color: white;
}` in my css file and its posted in my opening post.

Comment: Great, in that case just please try to add the `!important` next to that, so that it will be: `.menu-icon { color: white !important; }`. After you do that, please check in the dev tools (Chrome) or Firebug (Firefox) if the style has been applied (after you refresh the page) to the icon by inspecting the icon element.

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead `<i class="icon ion-home light"></i>`for white or `<i class="icon ion-home balanced"></i>` for green.
You can customize the colors in the sass file.

```
For example, you might change some of the default colors:
$light:                           #fff !default;
$stable:                          #f8f8f8 !default;
$positive:                        #387ef5 !default;
$calm:                            #11c1f3 !default;
$balanced:                        #33cd5f !default;
$energized:                       #ffc900 !default;
$assertive:                       #ef473a !default;
$royal:                           #886aea !default;
$dark:                            #444 !default;
```