# Change the color of the menu toggle button in sass

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using the default starting side menu and sass.

How can I change the color of the menu toggle button ?

Here is the html of the button I am trying to style :

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
    </button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

I am new to Ionic and sass.

Comment: Try using the steps form this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465136/ionic-change-ion-navicon-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the bar-stable-text variable in the ionic.app.scss is the standard way to do it:

```
$bar-stable-text: #fff;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your style.css change this :

```
.bar-stable .button{
   color: #red !important;
}
```